Azure update deployment
I have deployed the a node-16 based web application on Azure and also added some custom domain name but after sometime I have changed verious thing on the website.
But now if I want to redeploy from vs code . Out of 4 task of deployment it only complete 2 and the says "Deployment aborted" how can I fix this can any one help
I have tried in vs code for azure deployment.

share your web app code

Sorry I can't share the Code the code is confidential. Its company code.

We're going to need some more information than a generic "deployment aborted" message. That might mean a simple reproducible test-case. That might mean stack-traces or other additional diagnostics.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Robinkumar is it compulsory to deploy from VS code or any other alternative is okay.?

Hi everyone, I would like to thank you all for your support. I figured out the issue. I found out that even though its getting rejected on VS code but in the Azure Service its getting deployed ( I dont know the exact issue). To find the solution of I have searched on github and I got to know that this was a well known issue for VS code but its not solved yet. its not actually the vs code problem but the extension issue.
